# with the subprocess module in python, is it possible to run ssh as admin

Tags: python, ssh, subprocess

when i try to run a subprocess (in windows 10) that connects to ssh, i get:

```
Warning: Identity file 'C:\Users\rndom\.ssh\ssh-keys\rndom' not accessible: No such file or directory.
```

i've tried running the python script from a cmd with admin privileges, but it returns the same error.

i was able to connect with plink, so not sure why the issues here.  my goal is to just run an initial connection so that i can get the host key into the known_hosts file.

for that reason i am using Popen:

```
from remoteSSH import *
import json
from pathlib import Path, PureWindowsPath
import subprocess
import getpass
import time

ssh_connect = rf"ssh -tt -i 'C:\Users\{getpass.getuser()}\.ssh\ssh-keys\{server['HOST_USER']}' {server['HOST_USER']}@{server['HOST_IP']}"
ssh_parsed = shlex.split(ssh_connect)

try:
    with Popen(ssh_parsed, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE) as proc:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        proc.stdin.flush()
        proc.stdin.write(('yes'+'\n').encode('utf-8'))  # needs to be in bytes
        proc.stdin.flush()
        proc.wait()
        proc.stdin.close()
        proc.stdout.close()
        proc.terminate()
```

i've also tried running as admin as a test:

```
run_as_admin = rf'runas /noprofile /user:{getpass.getuser()} notepad.exe\n'
admin_parsed = shlex.split(run_as_admin)
with Popen(admin_parsed , stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE) as proc:
```

doesn't work

edit: i rather not use paramiko or whatever...

Comment: Are you sure if this path `C:\Users\rndom\.ssh\ssh-keys\rndom` exists?

Comment: @AnhPC03 yeah, i ran this out of an admin cmd and it works - outside of python i mean